# order_by() and latest() returning different queryset values

Tags: django, database, postgresql, python-2.7, orm

Querying the database using `order_by('date') and latest('date')` is returning different instance..... which is the best method to get the latest the instance?

I am using python 2.7 and django1.8.19

```
from apps.model import MyModel

def function():
latest_ins = MyModel.objects.filter(member=member).latest('date').date
latest_ins = MyModel.objects.filter(member=member).order_by('date').first().values('date')
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#latest), latest works with dates and will return one instance, the most recent object according to the specified parameter. So it does sorting and filtering.

`order_by` will in contrast sort objects but don't filter it. In your example, `order_by('date')` will sort your object chronologically, the oldest elements first and the most recent last. `order_by('date').first()` is the the equivalent of `earliest('date')`. That's why you don't get the same instances. You should either do `order_by('-date').first()` or `order_by('date').last()`.

Which one to use? I'd go for latest() or earliest() as it's easier to read an less prone to error.

Note: you should really consider to move to Django 2.2 as 1.7 is no longer supported. Similarly, if you can, use python 3.x.